# How to turn a string | string[] into string[]

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a response back from nodejs that is of type `string | QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[]` but I need it to be only of type `string[]`. How can I do this in typescript?

The background on the issue: nodejs is returning `string | QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[]` from `req.query`, but I need in to be a `string[]` only when I'm using typeORM with a where in clause.

Here's my code so far, which does not work:

```
import { In } from "typeorm";    
const { investmentIds } = req.query;
const historicalReturns = await historicalReturnRepository.find({
    where: In(investmentIds)
});
```

Comment: `const { investmentIds } = req.query as string[];` ?

Comment: That gives me this issue: `Conversion of type 'ParsedQs' to type 'string[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'ParsedQs' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2352)`

Comment: Ah, sorry, `where: In(investmentIds as string[])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asserting req.query to a string[] does not change it's true type, all it does it tell TS to treat it like a string[] when doing it's type checking. As such, it can cause errors when not used with a good reason. I have definitely seen people confuse assertions with an actual practical change in object type which it is not.

if you need to ensure your processing code gets an array, then you can say something like

```
const { investmentIds } = req.query
const idArr = Array.isArray(investmentIds) ? investmentIds : [investmentIds];
```

then use idArr which we now know is an array.